# Customizing colours for Candlestick chart while using google charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm sure there has to be a way, but after reviewing the documentation found [here](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/candlestickchart.html), I'm at a loss. The closest thing that I can find that would change the colour of the candlestick is the colors: flag under options, but it only changes the colour itself. The code I have still has it where an increase is the first colour specified, while a decrease in value is shown as the same colour, only as the border instead of the candlestick being filled.

The code I'm using is the controlrangefinder code found [here](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#chartrangefilter_control)